# Selenium Java: Why I cannot find buttons with a specific text using xpath?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get the element `<button>` with text 'Day'.

Using the proper way to get the element I cannot found it:

```
WebElemen dayButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Day']"));
```

Instead, I have to find the button element in this way:

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button"));
        for (WebElement button : buttons) {
            if (button.getText().equals("Day")) {
                System.out.println("Button found");
                button.click();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Does the word 'Day' have any surrounding space? Try some normalize-space function for text if so...

Comment: Can you post the html?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, this line of code is incorrect

```
WebElemen dayButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[text()='Day'"));
```

`driver.findElements` always returns a List. So if you need to find a single `WebElement` that has an exact match of the text `Day`, use this:

```
WebElement dayButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Day']"));
```

This can also be used:

```
WebElement dayButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.='Day']"));
```

**Note:** the fact that the second code snippet is working indicates that there are no leading and trailing spaces in the HTML for button text. However, if there are leading and trailing spaces in the text use the `normalize-space()` function in the xpath to handle it.

Comment: Putting the driver.findElements was a mistake when I wrote the question. I referred to driver.findElement. Thanks for the answer